# Handlebar helper showing the same date for every post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

So I have a site where users can make posts and I want the date at which they made it to be displayed on the post. To do this I am using momentjs and a handlebar helper.

helpers/hbs.js

```
 formatDate: function (date, format) {
    return moment(date).format(format);
  },
```

and my handlebar `{{{formatDate date 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a'}}}`

Just to note I have already registered the handlebar helper

```
const { formatDate, ifCond } = require('./helpers/hbs');
app.engine(
  '.hbs',
  exphbs({
    helpers: { formatDate, ifCond },
    defualtLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
  })
);
```

The problem is that it is showing the same date for every post. When I put the mongoose createdAt, it displays the correct date for each post but in a unformatted way. I've been looking for solutions and still can't find one.

Comment: When it is showing the same date for every post, which date does it show?

Comment: It shows the current date

Comment: What does the value of the `date` argument to the `formatDate` helper look like if you were to `console.log(date)`?

Comment: it's logging undefined

Comment: @76484 I think the problem may be that date is not wrapped in posts. However when I do something like `{{posts formatDate date h:mm a'}}` I get an error

Comment: The `undefined` means that you do not have a `date` property on your post Object. Do you know what properties your post Object has? Should it be `createdAt`?

Comment: @76484 yeah that's what I was struggling with. I am able to put `{{createdAt}} ` in my index file but I can't get the date formatted so its just that ugly mongoose date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically my problem was that I had to put createdAt inside my hbs handler and index file.

```
 // createdAt is the date saved in mongodb
formatDate: function (createdAt, formatDate) {
console.log(createdAt);
return moment(createdAt).format(formatDate); 
 },



{{formatDate createdAt 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a'}}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: The _argument_ needed to be `createdAt`. The `formatDate` function could have been left with the parameter `date`.

Comment: @76484 yeah I was just wondering why it worked with both. Thanks!!